# How to use regex sub to different item in string list?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Let's say I have `string list sList[ 'aaa', 'bbb', ccc']`
I want to use re.sub to change first match with 'aaa', second match with 'bbb', and third match with 'ccc'. (matches number with index number in the list)

```
stringToSearch = 'zzz is zzz is zzz'
```

I've tried using

```
re.sub( 'zzz', sList.pop(0), stringToSearch )
```

but it just turns out replacing all matches with 'aaa'.

BTW, I'm using `Python 3.6` and re module.

Comment: Can you include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @PJProudhon added more details

Comment: Not an expert at python, but looks like the replacement parameter is transmitted by value. You'd need maybe a custom function which would use a list by reference, or simply code a for-loop?

Comment: Yeah I can use for-loop, but just wondering if there's a way that can directly do it without a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, just use `replace()` with count 1:

```
for s in sList:
    stringToSearch = stringToSearch.replace('zzz', s, 1)
```

With `re.sub()`, it's similar, specify the count as 1:

```
for s in sList:
    stringToSearch = re.sub( 'zzz', s, stringToSearch, 1 )
```

Or use `re.sub()` directly:

```
re.sub('zzz', lambda _: sList.pop(0), stringToSearch, len(sList) or -1)
```

The reason for `len(sList) or -1` is `re.sub()` will still throw exception if `sList` is empty and `count` is 0, this `-1` can suppress this exception.

Comment: The code above doesn't work as it will always replace only the first zzz with 'ccc'.
The whole loop is basically like this:
1st s in sList: replace first 'zzz' with 'aaa'
2nd s in sList: replace first 'zzz' with 'bbb'
3rd s in sList: replace first 'zzz' with 'ccc

Comment: @RobertoSalim Code tested with your original input. Please copy it correctly, it's `stringToSearch = stringToSearch.replace('zzz', s, 1)`, **not** a single `stringToSearch.replace('zzz', s, 1)`

Comment: @RobertoSalim A method without `for` loop also added.

Comment: @JoeIddon `for` loop always works, if the occurrence of `'zzz'` is not enough, `replace()` and `sub()` do  nothing, it's the desired behavior.

Comment: @liliscent Ok, didn't realise that! +1 from me :)

Comment: @liliscent you're right, sorry, I didn't test it correctly. There's however a loophole in your current logic if the string that you replace has one string that equals to the string you're replacing. e.g. `sList = ['zzz', 'bbb', 'ccc]`. Where it will ended up replacing bbb to the first match and ccc to second match. What if I always want to replace first match with first string in sList regardless of it is 'zzz' or not (and second match with second string and so on)?
Upvoted as well, as it works according to what I mentioned in the question :)

Comment: @liliscent, ah nevermind me, your `re.sub()` code in the solution caters for that case. Do you mind to explain what does that lambda with underscore and colon do? Thanks again `lambda _:`

Comment: @RobertoSalim Now the final `re.sub()` solution can handler all cases.

Comment: @liliscent ok, but it behaves differently as well without the `lambda _:`. If I just use `sList.pop(0)` in the `re.sub()` it will just replace all matches with the sList's first element, which is 'aaa' in this case. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: `re.sub()` support 2 syntax, one is to specify a string to replace, the second is a function as a callback when a match is found. In your case you need a callback instead of a fixed string, thus a lambda function. The `_` in lambda is actually a match object, but here we don't use it.

Comment: @liliscent thank you for your explanation. I will do more readings on callback to try to understand it better :)